# How to use sql to select an element based on the result of another query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `TABLE_1`  and `TABLE_2`.

```
TABLE_1 : Line_id | Fail_id
              1        2
              2        3
TABLE_2 : Fail_id | Fail_reason
              1       "nrc"
              2       "lkc"
              3       "llc"
```

How do I get `Fail_resason` for `Line_id = 1` using a single query?I can do this using two queries but I have to use only 1 query.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join two tables like so:

```
 SELECT t2.Fail_reason
 FROM TABLE_1 as t1 JOIN TABLE_2 as t2 on t1.Fail_id = t2.Fail_id 
 WHERE t1.Line_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below query. This will give you output for all records. You can add `WHERE` condition if you need to filter output for specific Line_id.

```
SELECT t1.Line_id, t2.Fail_reason
 FROM TABLE_1 t1 JOIN TABLE_2 t2 ON t1.Fail_id = t2.Fail_id;
```